# Get the Nth Term in the Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: performance, c, fibonacci-sequence, c99

I'm trying out a new editor (CLion) and I decided to try an old well known programming problem. I also decided to try out C99 rather than C89.

This program calculates the nth term of the [Fibonacci Sequence](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/fibonacci-sequence.html) where the value of the current term is the sum of the 2 previous terms. The first 4 terms are 0, 1, 1, 2. The upper limit applied in the program is the 91st term, on my computer using `long long` the term value goes negative at 93rd term.

All Comments and observations are appreciated. I'm especially interested in performance, function and variable names and suggestions about how I can increase the range of terms using integers. I know I can use doubles but that may incur floating point errors at some point. As far as performance goes, the program has a nice small memory signature (0.5% of the system memory) speed is where I would be worried.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static const int MinimumTerm = 0;
static const int MaximumTerm = 91;
static const int MaxTries = 3;
static const int inputFailure = -1;

static int getTermCount()
{
    char *fmtstr = "Please enter an integer value between %d and %d\n";
    printf(fmtstr, MinimumTerm, MaximumTerm);

    int term = 0;
    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &term);
        if (count < MaxTries)
        {
            if (term < MinimumTerm || term > MaximumTerm)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, fmtstr, MinimumTerm, MaximumTerm);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return inputFailure;
        }
        count++;
    } while (term < MinimumTerm || term > MaximumTerm);

    return term;
}

static long long getNthFibonacciTerm(int term)
{
    int termCount = 2;
    long long prevValue = 0;
    long long nthValue = 1;

    switch  (term)
    {
        case 0: return 0;
        case 1: return 1;
    }

    while  (termCount < term)
    {
        long long newValue = prevValue + nthValue;
        prevValue = nthValue;
        nthValue = newValue;
        termCount++;
    }

    return  nthValue;
}

int main()
{
    int term = getTermCount();
    if (term < MinimumTerm)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Input\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("The %d term of the Fibonacci Sequence is %lld\n", term, getNthFibonacciTerm(term));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A few points about improving code

   - It seems that your naming convention for constants is to use a capitalized identifier. If so, that should be applied consistently for all constants including `inputFailure`.
   - The loop in the function `getTermCount` can be simplified. A for-loop is clearer IMO.
   - The output of `getNthFibonacciTerm` is actually off by one term (assuming the sequence starts with 0 at index 0). It outputs `1` for input `3`. The conditional checks before the loop could also be avoided to simplify the code.
   - Since the Fibonacci sequence is non-negative, the output could use an unsigned integer to allow slightly larger inputs.
2. About input range: since the output exceeds the limit of `unsigned long long` when the input is over 93, I do not see how it can be accurately represented unless you try to implement representations of big integers yourself in C.
3. About performance: there are several \$\Theta(\log n)\$ algorithms for computing Fibonacci numbers for a given input \$n\$. If you want that, [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/) is a list of all algorithms.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static const int MinimumTerm = 0;
static const int MaximumTerm = 93;
static const int MaxTries = 3;
static const int InputFailure = -1;

static int getTermCount()
{
    const char *fmtstr = "Please enter an integer value between %d and %d\n";

    for (int count = 0; count < MaxTries; count++)
    {
        int term;

        printf(fmtstr, MinimumTerm, MaximumTerm);    // IMO it is fine to just output to stdout before all attempts fail
        scanf("%d", &term);
        if (term >= MinimumTerm && term <= MaximumTerm)
        {
            return term;
        }
    }

    return InputFailure;
}

static unsigned long long getNthFibonacciTerm(int term)
{
    unsigned long long nthValue = 0;
    unsigned long long nextValue = 1;  // (n+1)th value, you may find a better name for that

    for (int termCount = 0; termCount < term; termCount++)
    {
        unsigned long long newValue = nthValue + nextValue;
        nthValue = nextValue;
        nextValue = newValue;
    }

    return nthValue;
}

int main()
{
    int term = getTermCount();
    if (term == InputFailure)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Input\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("The %d term of the Fibonacci Sequence is %llu\n", term, getNthFibonacciTerm(term));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the list of algorithms, I appear to be using a variant of one of them.

Comment: Just FYI, on code review providing an alternate solution generally lowers the score you receive in an answer. You did a good job on the observations that start your answer.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I am relatively new here. I wonder what qualifies as "an alternate solution"? Providing a brand new algorithm definitely qualifies. What about small variations that simplify the code logic (like I do here)?

Comment: You can provide code that enhances your comments for certain points, such as naming conventions for the constants. Providing a full updated version of the code in the question goes too far. If I was a student that posted the code for my homework or a take home test your answer is definitely too much. Someone might take exception to to the `if` control construct that returns the term from the input because it isn't using a best practice such as always adding braces around the `return term`.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Thanks for the clarification. I've added the braces by the way.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have seen many occasions an alternative solution got more votes than a thorough review without suggested alternative.

Comment: You might want to look at the discussion in the 2nd Monitor. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor

Answer (score 1):

Suggest using `uint64_t` (from the header file: `stdint.h`) rather than `long long`

Comment: Or, for an even greater range, try whether your compiler defines `uint128_t`.

Comment: @RolandIllig Apparently my compiler and header file don't include uint128_t.